# W3 CSS Validation Error

Tags: css

This is the error message when I check my site at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/:

> Value Error : border-style Too many values or values are not
>   recognized : 0

```
.style2 {
background-color : #889B25;
text-align : center;
background-image : url('images/tile3_green.jpg');
}
.style6 {
text-align : center;
}
.style7 {
font-size : xx-small;
}
.style9 {
text-align : center;
font-family : "AR CENA";
font-size : x-large;
color : #339933;
}
.style10 {
text-align : left;
}
.style11 {
color : #339933;
}
.style12 {
text-align : left;
color : #339933;
}
.style13 {
background-image : url('images/tile1.gif');
}
```

Comment: The CSS you posted doesn't produce the error

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the css you've posted. What this message means is that somewhere on your page you have css property `border-style` set incorrectly. So look for it and see how `border-style` should be set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to look for it now.

Comment: I found this border style on my tags:

<img style="border: 0" id="img3" src="images/button23.gif"

Does this make an error in CSS validation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that does!! Change that to `border: none`

Comment: No, `border: 0` causes no such message, as you can easily check. The error message would be triggered by `border-style: 0` for example.

Comment: Well, you are right, that's just the width of 0. So, @user1888673, why don't you post a link to your site or search for border-style better and show us the code?